# Why is Ansible still able to connect node without ssh

Tags: ssh, ansible

I created two ubuntu docker containers one with control node and another with slave. I ran

```
ansible all -m service -a "name=ssh state=stopped"
```

and it shows

```
172.18.0.3 | CHANGED => {
    "changed": true, 
    "name": "ssh", 
    "status": {
        "enabled": {
            "changed": false, 
            "rc": null, 
            "stderr": null, 
            "stdout": null
        }, 
        "stopped": {
            "changed": true, 
            "rc": 0, 
            "stderr": "", 
            "stdout": " * Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd\n   ...done.\n"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to ssh manually it failed because the openssh server has stopped which is fine. Then I ran another ansible command to start it.

```
# ansible all -m service -a "name=ssh state=started"
172.18.0.3 | CHANGED => {
    "changed": true, 
    "name": "ssh", 
    "status": {
        "enabled": {
            "changed": false, 
            "rc": null, 
            "stderr": null, 
            "stdout": null
        }, 
        "started": {
            "changed": true, 
            "rc": 0, 
            "stderr": "", 
            "stdout": " * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd\n   ...done.\n"
        }
    }
}
```

I am quiet amazed how was ansible able to connect to the node when I have already stopped the ssh service of the node ? Is there some alternative method that ansible is connecting to node other than ssh?

Comment: It is likely using the Docker Python SDK which in turn is using the Docker Server REST API. SSH is not involved here as no external server is being accessed according to the info provided.

Comment: When both are just a docker container can they use the docker api inside the container ?

Comment: you can run your command appending '-vvvvv' and hopefully will see more info about how it connects to the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible can connect to targets through a variety of protocols.

Take a look at the [connection plugins list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection.html#plugin-list)

In your case, for Docker containers, it uses the Docker API.